# Is there any svn C API examples for version 1.8.1?

Tags: c, api, svn, sample, svn-api

I need to checkout & update files to local path with SVN API(version 1.8.1). 
The examples in svn source code are of little help.

Any examples for `svn_client_checkout3()` and `svn_client_update3()`?

Comment: Have you tried posting on the [Subversion Dev Mailing List](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-dev/)?

Comment: That mailing list is for discussion of development of Subversion itself. For users of the API, you should start on the SVN **Users** mailing list. If it's more appropriate for the Dev list, you'll be redirected there.

Answer (score 1):

There are some C++ wrappers in [pysvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org/) which demonstrate `svn_client_checkout` and `svn_client_update`:

- [Py::Object pysvn_client::cmd_checkout](http://pysvn.tigris.org/source/browse/pysvn/trunk/pysvn/Extension/Source/pysvn_client_cmd_checkin.cpp?annotate=1553&sortby=date#id158)
- [Py::Object cmd_update](http://pysvn.tigris.org/source/browse/pysvn/trunk/pysvn/Extension/Source/pysvn.hpp?annotate=1554&sortby=date#id294)

**References**

- [pysvn_client_update](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_update)
- [pysvn_client_checkout](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_checkout)